# Using a ngFor to Filter list items or similar situation using a ngFor

Tags: angular

Curious if anyone knows a way to Filter with a ngFor that **doesnt** require an entire **Pipe** to be built for it, I just need to see if x = 'heroes' Dont show it, else show it type thing so I can have live feedback on the list.

So

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of entries; let i = index" class=" personal"> //can I filter this to see if x.hero = heroes
```

Or is there a way to say:

```
 <div *ngIf="{{x.hero}} == 'heroes'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you states, the correct way to do it is with a pipe, however:

If you want to combine ngFor with ngIf, you can run the ngFor in ng-container - which doesnt create an actual element on the DOM, then add the ngIf inside that, the html would look something like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of entries">
  <div *ngIf="x.hero == 'heroes'">
    {{ x | json }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

see working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-for-with-ng-if?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You can see nothing gets rendered for elements which don't qualify the condition inside the ngIf